# How to create stack overflow comment with external website link

Tags: support, comments, markdown

I have come across comments such as below.

[image]
Which contains link to external website but `http` url does not show up in the comment instead user provided word come up, upon clicking that word will lead to external website(example "help center", "Minimum, Complete and Verifiable example").

Comment: Already answered in section "How can I format and link in comments?" in the FAQ [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a simple markdown pattern, just type `[word](link)`.

For some of the words there are even (site specific) predefined link expansions, e.g. `[MCVE]` will expand to the linked source with wording `Minimal, Complete and Verifyable example`.

Comment: [thank you](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=thank+you&rlz=1C1GGRV_enIN795IN795&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=Ah3N-wkyJfTiIM%253A%252CteLRslchXvFsgM%252C_&usg=AI4_-kQsrXsuv3QybN327xJWDvp_bJUgzg&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiE1f-Arc_dAhVFOY8KHdwuDkEQ9QEwBHoECAMQDA#imgrc=Ah3N-wkyJfTiIM:)

Comment: I tried `[MCVE](link )` on stack overflow but it did not expand. Am I missing something?

Comment: @kiranBiradar Be sure not to have any blank characters at beginning or end of the link.

Comment: Yes   I am  sure..

Comment: @kiranBiradar Then I don't know what's gone wrong, it works just the same way as you did here usually.

Comment: [MCVE] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) This worked for me. We need to have space between [MCVE] and (link).

Comment: @kiranBiradar The `[MCVE]` magic tag only expands at the Stack Overflow site.

Comment: Yes, Indeed. There only I have tried.